# Is Tensorflow worth using for simple optimization problems?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have started learning Tensorflow recently and I am wondering if it is worth using in simple optimization problems (least squares, maximum likelihood estimation, ...) instead of more traditional libraries (scikit-learn, statsmodel)?

I have implemented a basic AR model estimator using Tensorflow with MLE and the AdamOptimizer and the results are not convincing either performance or computation speed wise.

What do you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is somewhat opinion based, but Tensorflow and similar frameworks such as PyTorch are useful when you want to optimize an arbitrary, parameter-rich non-linear function (e.g., a deep neural network). For a 'standard' statistical model, I would use code that was already tailored to it instead of reinventing the wheel. This is true especially when there are closed-form solutions (as in linear least squares) - why go into to the murky water of local optimization when you don't have to? Another advantage of using existing statistical libraries is that they usually provide you with measures of uncertainty about your point estimates.

I see one potential case in which you might want to use Tensorflow for a simple linear model: when the number of variables is so big the model can't be estimated using closed-form approaches. Then gradient descent based optimization makes sense, and tensorflow is a viable tool for that.